# Can I open a custom modal form for Microsoft Word?

Tags: .net, com, ms-word, add-in, modal-dialog

I am working on a project which uses Word automation through VSTO add-ins and I would need to open a modal form from(or over) the Word process launched by the .Net framework. The modal form should be able to execute operations on the opened Word document. 
Could you please guide me in the right direction for solving this problem? I have searched for a solution but I'm completely new to COM programming and add-ins(and interop for that matter) and I don't seem to find anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer was right under my nose. It is possible to open a modal dialog form in .NET from within the addin.
Here is the link that explains it:
http://codeidol.com/csharp/c-sharp-in-office/Using-Windows-Forms-in-VSTO/Introduction/